# Plotting Polynomial Regression in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I'm trying to plot a polynomial model using Matplotlib but it always plots multiple lines and I don't know how to fix it. I looked up multiple websites but couldn't find anything helpful.

[My data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmyKE.png)

Here is the code:

```
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 3, include_bias = False)
poly.fit(X_train)

X_train_transformed = poly.transform(X_train)
X_test_transformed = poly.transform(X_test)

model_poly = LinearRegression()
model_poly.fit(X_train_transformed, Y_train)
print("Test accuracy: " + str(model_poly.score(X_test_transformed, Y_test)))
print("Train accuracy: " + str(model_poly.score(X_train_transformed, Y_train)))

Y_predicted_poly = model_poly.predict(X_test_transformed)

plt.figure(figsize = (12,8))
plt.scatter(X_train, Y_train, label = "Train")
plt.scatter(X_test, Y_test, label = "Test")
plt.plot(X_test, Y_predicted_poly, color = "green", label = "Regression")
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Temperature")
plt.title("Polynomial Regression", fontsize = 16)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you please post an example of the image so we can see? My guess is that the shape of your data is wrong but I can't know unless you share the photo. Try to check the shape to see if it is incorrect.

Comment: I've added an image, I tried reshaping X_test/Y_predicted_poly without any luck.

Comment: Yes, but what are the shapes?

Comment: Both are (21, 9)

Comment: mcve stands for [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

You're 'connecting the dots' but the data isn't ordered - change

```
plt.plot(X_test, Y_predicted_poly, color = "green", label = "Regression")
```

to

```
plt.scatter(X_test, Y_predicted_poly, color = "green", label = "Regression")
```

and I blv things will look a bit better. Alternatively, order your X_test from small to large (or vice versa) before calculating the Y_predicted_poly.  Or, dont use a line in plt.plot:

```
plt.plot(X_test, Y_predicted_poly, 'go', label = "Regression")
```